# Identifying Tab / Window to click a button using JavaScript (AppleScript)

Tags: javascript, html, safari, applescript

I am trying to get an Apple Script to click on an item within webpage.

I'm using the following script

```
   tell application "Safari"
     delay 5
     do JavaScript "document.getElementById('Menu Principal').click();" in current tab of first window
   end tell
```

However my output us "missing value". I think that the problem is that I'm not selecting the right tab or window to click at.

This is my first time using applescript and other examples and question in Stackoverflow are somewhat similar but I'm still missing something

I'm attaching the webpage source code.

Thanks!

http://s328.photobucket.com/user/sergioguerra1/media/ScreenShot2014-03-13at114430AM_zps6919a8ce.png.html